# oracle 18c en Ubuntu16

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu

Estoy intentando instalar Oracle 18c en Ubuntu Server 16
Llegado a un punto de la instalación lanza el error:
"Error al llamar al destino install"
Hay documentación sobre como instalar Oracle 12c en Ubuntu como:
[Tutorial en 12c](https://soajp.blogspot.com/2016/06/instalar-base-de-datos-oracle-12c-en.html)

Pero no encuentro la solución a este error.
¿Alguna ayuda?
Gracias
Un saludo!

Actualización: También he intentado copiar los ficheros .mk correspondientes al error según esta guía: [Codigo61Blog](http://codigo61.blogspot.com/2018/01/como-instalar-oracle-12c-en-linux_12.html)
[image: Eror] pero sin éxito.

Incluso como dicen aquí: [solución](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4031920) en el comentario de user5212244

editando: env_plsql.mk
Find:

LDFLAGS=-o $@ $(LDOBJSZ) $(LDPLATFORMFLAGS) $(LDPATHFLAG)$(PRODLIBHOME) $(LDPATHFLAG)$(LIBHOME) $(LDSTUBLIBS)

Modify to:

LDFLAGS=-o $@ $(LDOBJSZ) $(LDPLATFORMFLAGS) $(LDPATHFLAG)$(PRODLIBHOME) $(LDPATHFLAG)$(LIBHOME) -Wl,--no-as-needed $(LDSTUBLIBS)

Pero nuevamente sin éxito.

Comment: dale un cat /tmp/install.... | grep ORA- para ver el error que te manda!

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!MZliWCIB!8Msvr1_XXWGClezFBUGFFGISlUUUay31Rl2GsbxyvNE

Comment: con grep ORA- no salía nada, pero con grep ORA si, está en ese fichero.log

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. El mensaje de error incluye el nombre del _log_ que genera el instalador. ¿has buscado allí el posible fallo? debiera explicarse con claridad a partir de ese punto. Un saludo.

Comment: INFORMACIÓN: 
make: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo '/tmp/lib/libpls12.a', necesario para 'wrap'.  Alto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente, resolví este error, y aunque salieron otros finalmente todo fue solucionado 100% y Oracle 18c instalado en Ubuntu sin problemas.
He documentado el proceso en: [Guía Instalar Oracle 18c en Ubuntu](https://suevaristo.blogspot.com/2018/11/instalar-oracle-database-18c-en-ubuntu.html) por si a alguien le pudiese ayudar.

Un saludo.

Comment: no coloques en el título, la leyenda solucionado; así no funciona la plataforma, en su lugar amplia tu propia respuesta y después aceptala dando clic en el ícono de la palomita que es justo a lado

Comment: Oh, no sabía, gracias!